# Capturing real time video while still using arduino

Tags: video, arduino, microcontroller

As the title says, I would like to capture real time video while still using arduino, however, not in that I must connect the camera directly to it, I want to use the arduino Uno for navigation, but use something else in correlation and either use the Wifi shield that arduino has, or some sort of feature that another micro controller that you would know so that I could send the information(the live feed) back to a computer, I would like all of this to be done without any sort of wire so wifi would be the most preferable solution.

From my research I found the mDVR3 however, I did not find anywhere to purchase it, nor did I find any good documentation on it's possibility of sending the data, not just storing it, even though I know it has 32GB of space.
*EDIT : And yes I am aware that the arduino does not have enough juice to ever do more then take video with extremly low fps

Comment: Any realistic solution is going to have the arduino outside the video path and either in parallel to it or using some sub channel provided by the video gear, rather than trying to be part of the video channel.

Comment: I am aware of that, I said that in my question, I wanted to know how and if it would be possible to use the arduino wifi shield or anything else to get the feed transmited back to me.

Comment: If you have some way to read out an image at a rate the arduino can manage, you can push the data through the wifi shield and manage to make a very slow sequence-of-pictures type of "video".  Maybe you can find a source which is at least JPEG encoded and do a sort of fake mjpeg (or even a real one, perhaps with fixup at the receiving side).  But the quality is likely to be very poor compared to what could be achieved with the same expenditure on more suitable parts - you can probably get a complete wireless IP camera/baby monitor for the price of an arduino, wifi shield, and compatible camera.

Comment: Yes, the best research turned out to give me around 1 frame per 4 seconds or more, if you know any proper hardware to handle all of that I d be very thankful, thank you nonetheless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [FPV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Person_View) setup. Currently they are common for radio control hobbyists.

To record video, a capture card device like the [EasyCap](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002H3BSCM) is used.

Wireless video transmitters/receivers are everywhere, frequencies include 900mhz/2.4ghz/5.8ghz. No programming required.

Overal structure:

Camera -> Video TX     ~~wireless~~   Video RX -> Capture card -> Computer

For navigation, the computer can do the image processing (the capture card both records video and can give it to your software to process), then tell the Arduino what to do on a different wireless protocol (wifi/bluetooth, etc).

Comment: could you please give me some example of a proper wireless video transmitter/receiver? And if you have previous experience with this maybe some access to some documentation about how to connect from camera to the transmitter? thank you

Comment: Cameras and transmitters use standard composite video (NTSC or PAL, NTSC for north america in general). You can get entire setups like these: http://hobbyking.com/hobbyking/store/__21327__900MHZ_200mW_Tx_Rx_1_3_inch_CCD_Camera_NTSC_520TVL.html